# Flutter - android_alarm_manager not working in other screen except main method in android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-alarms

I am working with [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager), and followed this steps:-

```
// 1. added permission

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

// 2. added  service and receiver

    <service
        android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver
        android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver
        android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

// 3. initialzing alarm manager 

    main() async {
     final int helloAlarmID = 0;
      await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
      runApp(...);
    }
```

when I add alarm in main() function, I'm getting **true** value for "val"

```
bool val = await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), helloAlarmID, printHello);
print("isAlarmServiceSet: $val");
```

but when I try to use this above line in other file like HomeScreen etc. it's returning false value and alarm is not set for alarm manager.

Can anyone sugegst me a solution for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: I am facing same problem, same code is working in main method but not on other screen like Home or Login screen. Kindly some one suggest a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Jay, did you got any solution of this issue, currently I am using https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus  and https://plus.fluttercommunity.dev/docs/android_alarm_manager_plus/usage/